# I'm creating a exam management project , trying to save the current radio button that been clicked and clear when move to another question

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Iam new to wpf C# and Iam trying to learn by creating my first project , I got Question in the stack Panel and when i click on a question it shows me a question and 4 answers as Radio Buttons and Iam trying to save the current Radio button that been clicked for the answer and when i click on another question all the radio buttons been cleared , so on my code when i click on another question all my radio buttons cleared but when i get back to the question that already been answered all the radio buttons cleared and the not saved  , here is my c# code :

```
using final_project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace final_project.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StudentExamWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StudentExamWindow : Window
    {
        
        private int CurrentQuestion;
        private int Grade = 0;
        List<int> qgrades = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).ToList();
        Exam exam1 = new Exam();
        List<Answer> answer1 = new List<Answer>();
        Question que = new Question();
        List<RadioButton> radioBoxes = new List<RadioButton>();
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
        TimeSpan time;


        public StudentExamWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            time = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            exam1.Id = "1234";
            exam1.Name = "math";
            exam1.ExamDate = DateTime.Now;
            exam1.Questions = new List<Question>();
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "1", Content = "12" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "2", Content = "16" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "3", Content = "17" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "4", Content = "18" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "1", Content = "50" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "2", Content = "60" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "3", Content = "70" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "4", Content = "80" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "1", Content = "50" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "2", Content = "60" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "3", Content = "70" });
            answer1.Add(new Answer { Id = "4", Content = "80" });
            addquestions(exam1.Questions);
        }

        //Add question
        private void addquestions(List<Question> questoins)
        {
            Question q = new Question();
            Question q2 = new Question();
            Question q3 = new Question();
            q.Id = "Q1";
            q.Name = "what 4 * 4 ? ";
            q.Grade = "10";
            q.Answers = answer1;
            q.CorrectAnswerId = "second";
            questoins.Add(q);
            q2.Id = "Q2";
            q2.Name = "what 4*79 ? ";
            q2.Grade = "10";
            q2.Answers = answer1;
            q2.CorrectAnswerId = "third";
            questoins.Add(q2);
            q3.Id = "Q3";
            q3.Name = "what 8*7 ? ";
            q3.Grade = "10";
            q3.Answers = answer1;
            q3.CorrectAnswerId = "forth";
            questoins.Add(q3);
            AddQuestionPannel(questoins);
           for(int i=0; i < buttons.Count; i++) 
            {
                buttons[i].Name = "Q" + (i + 1).ToString();
            }


        }

      //add Question pannel
        private void AddQuestionPannel(List<Question> q)
        {
             foreach(Question rs in q)
            {
                int i = 0;
                Button QB= new Button();
                QB.Content = rs.Name;
                QB.Background = Brushes.White;
                QuestionPannel.Children.Add(QB);
                QB.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ShowQuestion_Click);
                i++;
                buttons.Add(QB);

            }
        }
        //show the Question on the front of the page
        private void ShowQuestion(string name,int index)
        {
            int i = index - 1;
            int imul = i * 4;
            radioBoxes.Clear();
            Txtblock.Text = name;
            Exercise.Text = buttons[i].Content.ToString();
            first.Content = answer1[imul].Content;
            second.Content = answer1[imul+1].Content;
            third.Content = answer1[imul+2].Content;
            forth.Content = answer1[imul+3].Content;
            radioBoxes.Add(first); radioBoxes.Add(second); 
            radioBoxes.Add(third); radioBoxes.Add(forth);
        }

        private void AddGrade()
        {
            TextBlock gradeBlock= new TextBlock();
            gradeBlock.Text = Grade.ToString();
            CheckboxList.Children.Add(gradeBlock);
        }
        private bool CheckAnswer(string c,string correctanswer)
        {
      
            if (c==correctanswer)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool Buttonwasclicked = false;
        //show the question on the front of the page click
        private void ShowQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Buttonwasclicked)
            {
                foreach(RadioButton r in radioBoxes) 
                {
                    r.IsChecked = false;
                    Buttonwasclicked = true;
                }

            }
            SaveAnswer.Content = "Save Answer";
            int temp = 0;
            Exercise.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
            first.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
            second.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
            third.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
            forth.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
            SaveAnswer.Visibility= Visibility.Visible;
            string Btn_name = (sender as Button).Name.ToString();
            while("Q" + temp.ToString() != Btn_name)
            {
                temp++;
            }
            CurrentQuestion = temp-1;
            ShowQuestion(Btn_name,temp);

        }
        private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddToFinalGrade();
            AddGrade();
        }
        
        //save the current question's answer
        private void SaveAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveAnswer.Content = "Saved";
            int grade = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < radioBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (radioBoxes[i].IsChecked == true && CheckAnswer(radioBoxes[i].Name, exam1.Questions[CurrentQuestion].CorrectAnswerId))
                {

                    grade = 10;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    grade = 0;
                }
            }
            AddToGredeList(grade, CurrentQuestion);
        }

        private void AddToGredeList(int g, int i)
        {
            qgrades[i] = g;
        }
        private void AddToFinalGrade()
        {
            Grade = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < qgrades.Count; i++)
            {
                Grade += qgrades[i];
            }
        }

        private void first_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void second_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void third_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
        }

        private void forth_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
       
        }


        private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (time == TimeSpan.Zero) dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            else
            {
                time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
                MyTime.Text = time.ToString("c");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my XAMl Code:

```
<Window x:Class="final_project.View.StudentExamWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:final_project.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StudentExamWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Border Background="#eff2f7" CornerRadius="30">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Left Side-->
            <Grid Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4">
                <StackPanel Name="QuestionPannel">
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <!--Right Side-->
            <Border CornerRadius="30" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Title -->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                          Width="550"
                          Background="#2e3137">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <DatePicker Height="25" Width="115"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        Margin="10 10 10 0"
                                        Name="datePicker1"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Grid Margin="150,0,0,0">
                            <Label Name="Examtitle" Content="Exam Name"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   Margin="10" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <!--Question Show-->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Name="MyTime" Text="1:00:00" Margin="273,10,274,10" />
                        <TextBlock Name="StudentName" Text="Studentname" Margin="10,10,553,10" />
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4">
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="Exercise NAME" Name="Exercise" Visibility="Hidden"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Width="350"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,289" />
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Margin="0,-16,0,0">
                                <StackPanel Name="CheckboxList"  Width="350" Margin="69,23,0,37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="">
                                    <TextBlock Name="Txtblock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=""/>
                                    <RadioButton Name="first" Content="" Visibility="Hidden" Checked="first_Checked"/>
                                    <RadioButton Name="second" Content="" Visibility="Hidden" Checked="second_Checked"/>
                                    <RadioButton Name="third" Content="" Visibility="Hidden" Checked="third_Checked"/>
                                    <RadioButton Name="forth" Content="" Visibility="Hidden" Checked="forth_Checked"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="SaveAnswer" Content="Save Answer" 
                                            Visibility="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RoundButtonTemplate}" 
                                            Width="108" 
                                            Height="33"
                                            BorderBrush="Aqua" 
                                            Background="black" Click="SaveAnswer_Click"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>

                            <Button Name="Save" Content="Save All" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="551,231,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="31" Width="68" RenderTransformOrigin="0.859,1.023" Click="Save_Click">
                                <Button.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="0.332"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Button.RenderTransform>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Name="Exit" Visibility="Visible" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="551,271,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="72" Click="Exit_Click"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>



            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </Border>

</Window>
```

i tried to create an bool variable to check which Button as an question been clicked so i don't clear the radio buttons but still not working its clear the clicked and not clicked once

Comment: You must save the answer to a question. Then save the question (the original instance of the question object). Now when you go back to a question, you must get the saved and original question instance. Then read the answer and toggle the RadioButton accordingly.

Comment: That would be a lot easier if you would know how to use data binding [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0). It's not complicated but fundamental. You definitely should look into it.

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for the help , i'll look into data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example implements a small simple quiz using data binding and data templating to enable a dynamic UI (for example the number of choices can vary as the `RadioButton` elements are created dynamically). Because of the data binding the values of the view are automatically transferred and stored in the data models.
The example also shows how to design classes and their relationships properly using composition.

Hopefully the example helps you to understand how to apply fundamental WPF techniques

- [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)
- [How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples)
- [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

**Exam.cs**

```cs
class Exam : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Exam(IEnumerable<Question> questions)
  {
    this.Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>(questions);
    this.CurrentQuestionIndex = -1;
  }

  public void SelectNextQuestion()
  {
    // Prevent invalid index (too high)
    this.CurrentQuestionIndex = Math.Min(this.Questions.Count - 1, this.CurrentQuestionIndex + 1);

    this.CurrentQuestion = this.Questions[this.CurrentQuestionIndex];
  }

  public void SelectPreviousQuestion()
  {
    // Prevent invalid index (too low)
    this.CurrentQuestionIndex = Math.Max(0, this.CurrentQuestionIndex - 1);

    this.CurrentQuestion = this.Questions[this.CurrentQuestionIndex];
  }

  private Question currentQuestion;
  public Question CurrentQuestion
  {
    get => this.currentQuestion;
    set
    {
      this.currentQuestion = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }


  public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; }
  private int CurrentQuestionIndex { get; set; }

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Question.cs**

```cs
class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Question(string summary, Answer answer)
  {
    this.Summary = summary;
    this.Answer = answer;
  }

  private string summary;
  public string Summary
  {
    get => this.summary;
    set
    {
      this.summary = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private Answer answer;
  public Answer Answer
  {
    get => this.answer;
    set
    {
      this.answer = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Answer.cs**

```cs
class Answer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Answer(IEnumerable<string> optionSummaries, int validOptionIndex)
  {
    this.OptionSummaries = new ObservableCollection<string>(optionSummaries);
    this.ValidOptionIndex = validOptionIndex;
  }

  private string selectedOptionSummary;
  public string SelectedOptionSummary
  {
    get => this.selectedOptionSummary;
    set
    {
      this.selectedOptionSummary = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      this.IsCorrect = this.OptionSummaries.IndexOf(this.SelectedOptionSummary) == this.ValidOptionIndex;
      this.IsAnswered = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedOptionSummary);
    }
  }

  private bool isCorrect;
  public bool IsCorrect
  {
    get => this.isCorrect;
    private set
    {
      this.isCorrect = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private bool isAnswered;
  public bool IsAnswered
  {
    get => this.isAnswered;
    private set
    {
      this.isAnswered = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<string> OptionSummaries { get; }
  private int ValidOptionIndex { get; }

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private Exam Exam { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    var questions = new List<Question>()
    {
      new Question(
        "How many hours has a day?", // Question summary
        new Answer(new [] { "12", "8", "26", "24", "21" }, // Choices
        3)), // Index of correct choice
      new Question(
        "How many continents does the world have?", 
        new Answer(new [] { "5", "6", "7", "9", "10" }, 
        2)),
    };

    this.Exam = new Exam(questions);
    this.Exam.SelectNextQuestion();
    this.DataContext = this.Exam;
  }

  private void OnShowNextQuestionButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.Exam.SelectNextQuestion();

  private void OnShowPreviousQuestionButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    => this.Exam.SelectPreviousQuestion();

  private void OnOptionSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
    string? selectedOptionSummary = radioButton.Content as string;
    this.Exam.CurrentQuestion.Answer.SelectedOptionSummary = selectedOptionSummary;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Summary}" />
    
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Answer.OptionSummaries}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <!-- Define how each item should look like usng a DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate>
          <RadioButton GroupName="OptionSelector" 
                       Content="{Binding}" 
                       Click="OnOptionSelected" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Previous"
              Click="OnShowPreviousQuestionButtonClicked" />
      <Button Content="Next"
              Click="OnShowNextQuestionButtonClicked" />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Great example and helps a lot with my project and understanding Data binding